# MvvmCross 5.4 Crash on app startup with NullRef at ConsoleLogProvider

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, linker, mvvmcross

I've updated my Xamarin.Android app package `MvvmCross` from `5.3.2` to `5.4` and app start crashing on startup. Manually I identified that the reason is the linker - I have `link SDK libs only` option enabled. With the `None` option it works just fine but makes a twice bigger package.

> The type initializer for 'MvvmCross.Core.Platform.LogProviders.ConsoleLogProvider' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Can you add an issue in the repo: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a known bug in MvvmCross 5.4 and will be fixed in the next version.

In the meantime, as a work around, you can go to your `Setup` class and override `GetDefaultLogProviderType` so it returns `MvxLogProviderType.None`, like this:

```
protected override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType() 
    => MvxLogProviderType.None;
```

**EDIT**

Since the providers rely on reflection, if you wanna use the Console provider with `IMvxLog`, simply include this in your `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs`:

```
using System;

//[...]

public void Include(ConsoleColor color)
{
    Console.Write("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    color = Console.ForegroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer! And workaround which actually works perfectly. Appreciate your help

Comment: protected override MvxLogProviderType GetDefaultLogProviderType()
{
      return MvxLogProviderType.None;
}